# More elegant way in PHP to generate a query from array elements

Tags: php, sql

When I need to loop over something while generating a query from each element, I would use something like

```
$queryStr = "INSERT INTO tableName (x,y) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++)
{
   $queryStr .= "( ".$thing[$i]['x'].", ".$thing[$i]['b']."), ";
}
//extra code to remove the last  comma from string
```

Would there be an alternative? 
I don't mind performance too much (knowing the length of the array is not too big), just something that looks nicer.

Comment: If it is working for you then it should be fine. Although I think this logic will add an extra comma for the last pair which might cause errors with the query.

Comment: I think is better make an array instaed of string

Comment: also I think you will like make chunks, i dont know in mysql, but sql-server has a limit of 1000 for insert statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight improvement to get rid of last part (removing latest comma). You can first create an array of values, then use implode function like:

```
$queryStr = "INSERT INTO tableName (x,y) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++)
{
  $values[] = "( ".$thing[$i]['x'].", ".$thing[$i]['b'].")";
}
$queryStr .= implode(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a prepared statement:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tableName (x, y) VALUES (:x, :y)';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++)
{
  $sth->execute(array(
    ':x' => $thing[$i]['x'], 
    ':y' => $thing[$i]['b']));
}
```

More examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Do you know if mysql has a limit in the insert statatement like sql-server(1000 is the limit in sql-server)?

Comment: 1000 is the limit for adding values in an `in clause` in Oracle and SQL Server. I don't think that applies here, since it's just executing a statement with only 2 parameters and executing them separately.

Comment: thanks, I didnt know the other engines, in sql-server you have `insert into [table] ([field1],[field2])VALUES(values1),...(Values1000)` you will get an error on value1001

Comment: No, you are right, and MySQL probably has such a limit as well. It's just that my solution is different, because I execute the statement for each row. But note, that that might negatively affect performance, especially if you are inserting many rows.

Answer (score 1):

I like using `array_walk` and `implode` for things like this:

```
$values = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(4, 5, 6),
    . . .
);

// an array to hold the values to insert
$query = array();

// walk the values and build the query array
array_walk($values, function($v) use(&$query) {
    $query[] = "(" . implode(", ", $v) . ")";
});

// dump the output
echo implode(", ", $query);
```

The result looks like this:

```
(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), ...
```

Maybe not much cleaner, but at least it gets rid of the `for` loop :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `implode()` with `array_map()`:

```
implode(', ', array_map(function($v) { return '(' . $v['x'] . ', ' . $v['b'] . ')'; }, $things));
```

#### [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r8tUYQ)

Comment: This is a nice one-line solution. I like the use of array_map here - I wasn't familiar with that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $strCols =  '`'.implode('`, `',array_keys($arrValues)).'`'; //Sets the array keys passed in $arrValues up as column names
    if ($bolEscape){ //Checks if $bolEscape is true
            $arrValues = $this->escape($arrValues); //Calls the escape function
            $strValues = '"'.implode('","',array_values($arrValues)).'"'; //Sets the array values passed in $arrValues up as data for the columns
        }else{
            $strValues = '"'.implode('","',array_values($arrValues)).'"'; //Sets the array values passed in $arrValues up as data for the columns WITHOUT escaping
        }
            //Creates the SQL statement for the query
        $strSQL = 'INSERT INTO `' . $strTable . '` (' . $strCols . ') VALUES (' . $strValues . ')';
```

Thats part of the database class I have written... I pass in the arrValues ('ColumnName'=>'Value')